# mod_perl custom configuration directives don't work when placed in .htaccess and there is <Location>

Tags: apache-2.2, redmine, mod-perl

I'm trying to complete Redmine's feature request [#2693: Use Redmine.pm to authenticate for any directory](http://www.redmine.org/issues/2693) (1).
I have not much knowledge on all these things and need help.
Redmine uses `mod_perl` module [Redmine.pm](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/repository/changes/branches/2.2-stable/extra/svn/Redmine.pm) for authentication & authorization.
This module defines several custom configuration directives.
I've successfully modified patch from (1) and it works when all config is in `<Location>`:

```
<Location /digischrank/test>
        AuthType basic
        AuthName "Digischrank Test" 
        Require valid-user
        PerlAccessHandler Apache::Authn::Redmine::access_handler
        PerlAuthenHandler Apache::Authn::Redmine::authen_handler
        RedmineDSN "DBI:mysql:database=SomedaTaBAse;host=localhost" 
        RedmineDbUser "SoMeuSer" 
        RedmineDbPass "SomePaSS" 
        RedmineProject "digischrank" 
</Location>
```

But when I move one of these directives (`RedmineProject`, see (1)) in `.htaccess` file, Redmine.pm doesn't see it! I've tried to change `<Location>` to `<Directory>` and add `AllowOverride All`. Directives from `.htaccess` is visible, but remaining ones from `<Directory>` - not. I don't want to move all directives to each `.htaccess`. When I add `<Location>` in addition to `<Directory>`, again - only directives from `<Location>` are visible.

As far as I know, directives should be merged. I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that Redmine.pm doesn't provide DIR_MERGE function to merge configuration objects. See details in [Creating and Merging Configuration Objects](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/config/custom.html#Creating_and_Merging_Configuration_Objects) section of `mod_perl` manual. I've simplified given example because I need only override mode:

```
sub DIR_MERGE    { merge(@_) }

sub merge {
      my ($base, $add) = @_;
      my %mrg = ();
      for my $key (keys %$base, keys %$add) {
          next if exists $mrg{$key};
          # override mode
          $mrg{$key} = $base->{$key} if exists $base->{$key};
          $mrg{$key} = $add->{$key}  if exists $add->{$key};
      }
      return bless \%mrg, ref($base);
}
```